# Unable to open 2nd instance of eclipse when one is running currently on MacOS

Tags: eclipse, macos, terminal

Unable to open 2nd instance of Eclipse when one is running currently (continuous regression run) on macOS.

When I tried in terminal, I got the below message:

> "Script started, output file is /dev/null java_home: unrecognized
> option `--request` script done, output file is /dev/null"

Comment: What command are you using in terminal? That message doesn't sound like anything from Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal use the command:

```sh
open -n -a Eclipse
```

Note: You can only open a different workspace, Eclipse does not support two instances accessing the same workspace.